# calling function using ng-click after splitting word with ng-repeat (letter in letters)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

i am using two ng-repeat loops to initialize a table with 3 columns: user_name,script_name and cron_format. the only column user should be able to change is cron format, but i want to display each of the cron_format chars in its own `<input>` tag , so when user clicks the "minute" value, it will be the only one marked and not the all cron_format. after user edited the cron_format, i'm calling a simple function to compare the entire cron_format after user edited it. if change occurred, or in other words - cron_format before user edited != cron_format after user edited, function posts data to server.
this is my table:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="(user_id,row) in data">
<tr ng-repeat="(script_id, cron_format) in row" ng-init="oldCron = cron_format">
    <td class="userName">{{user(user_id)}}</td>
    <td class="scriptName">{{script(script_id)}}</td>
    <td class="cronFormat">
        <input type="text"  ng-model="cron_format" ng-blur="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format,oldCron)"/></td>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

i was able to create working function and the above tables works fine except entire cron_format presented in one input field.
i was also able to put each letter of cron_format in separated input field changing the cron_format `<td>` to:

```
<input type="text" ng-repeat="letter in letters(cron_format) track by $index" value="{{letter}}" ng-blur="saveCron(user_id,script_id,cron_format,oldCron)"/></td>
```

but the function wont work...this is the function + the split function:

```
 $scope.saveCron = function(userId,scriptId,cronFormat,oldCron){

        if (oldCron != cronFormat) {
            $.post("updateCronChange.php", "user_id=" + userId + "&script_id=" + scriptId + "&cron_format=" + cronFormat, function (data) {
                alert('cron format changed to:' + cronFormat);
            });
        }
    }

    $scope.letters = function(rawname) {
        var lettersarray = rawname.split('');
        return lettersarray;
    };
```

any idea how can i make the function work and place each of the cron_format letters in separate input field, so after changing one letter the saveCron() function will again be called using `ng-blur` and compare the entire cron to the one i initialized `oldCron` ?? thanks!

Comment: There is no ng-model on your input.

Comment: i tried adding ng-model on the input as well but it ended up not showing any data in the cron_format column

Comment: Do you have some example json as I'm not very familiar with the cron format?

Comment: i have a json but to save lines the cron_format looks like this */* * * * *, each asterisk can be replaced with a number

Comment: So is there a forward slash in the first textbox and the asterisks are separated by spaces?